# PrintWriter not writing to the file but I closed the writer? (java)

Tags: java, html, eclipse, printwriter

I'm trying to write some text to an html file as an output using PrintWriter, and the text isn't saving to the file.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
public class Creator 
{
static ArrayList<Character> grid = new ArrayList<Character>();
public static void main(String[]args) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    char[] alphabet={'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};

    for(int row=0;row<625;row++)
    {
            grid.add(alphabet[RandGen(0,25)]);
            //System.out.print(grid.get(out));
    }
    Creator.Output();
    System.out.println("Executed.");
}
public static int RandGen(int min, int max)
{
    Random ran = new Random();
    int randomNum = ran.nextInt(max) + min;
    return randomNum;
}
public static void Output()throws FileNotFoundException
{
    //File file=new File("wsm.html");
    //File.createNewFile();
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("wordsearchmaker.html");
    writer.println("<html>");
    writer.println("<table>");
    writer.println("tr");
    for(int j=0;j<25;j++)
    {
        //for(int k=0;k<25;k++)
    //  {
            System.out.println("<th>"+grid.get(j));
            writer.println("<th>"+grid.get(j));
    //  }

    }
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();

    System.out.println("Outputting...");
}

}
```

So I've checked that the methods are all running (hence the "outputting..."), and I system.out.printed the content that I'm intending to write to the file, which is outputting exactly what I want it to. It's supposed to output html code into a html file (named wordsearchmaker.html), but nothing is saving to the file. Everywhere I looked online just said to make sure I'm closing the writer, which I did.

Note: I am working in eclipse, which has always been kind of finicky with me, so I may be messing something up there? I don't usually work in eclipse so that's totally possible.

Comment: Is the file there, but without any content? Or you cannot find the file? I run the code above, and it creates the file, with ~30 lines in it (with `<th>` and stuff)

Comment: I created a file for it to edit, and when I run it there are no changes to the file.

Comment: When you created a file to be edited, then you're very likely looking at the wrong file. Provide the full path to `new PrintWriter("wordsearchmaker.html");` to be sure.

Comment: I was putting the path down incorrectly, so I just made a string var and set the absolutepath to it, and used that. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've opened the PrintWriter, which enables you to send data to the file. But you haven't actually opened or created a file.

Try first creating a new file and modifying it:

```
import java.io.File;

File newFile = new File ("LOCATION OF FILE");
```

Then, set your PrintWriter to use newFile.

Comment: No, this is not necessary.